# Need to extract a specific number from a string with several numbers using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I need to get 293 as an int from the string "1 to 20 of 293 total". I'm unable to do it using .replaceAll method. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
    String s = "1 to 20 of 88 total";
    String k [] = s.split("1 to 20 of");
    String t [] = k[1].split("total");
    System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(t[0].replaceAll("\\s+","")));
```

Comment: This doesn't help me since I'm capturing the string and storing it in a string variable  (Something like this: String numberOfPagesText = numberOfPages.getText();) so can't hard code it for automation.

Comment: So getting 293 from string means what is the generalized requirement.( eg :  getting a 3 digit number from  a string ? getting a number greater than 200 from a string ?)

Comment: It could be different depending on the test i am running. It could be "1 to 20 of 293 total", "1 to 20 of 35 total", 1 to 20 of 88 total" etc. I would need to get 293, 35, 88 in each of those examples

Comment: Now check whether the edited version helps you